# Ubuntu16.0.4 Postgresql9.4 offline install

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.4

I search url,they are for Linux centos,I don't know how to offline install it in ubuntu16.0.4 .

Any help will appreciated！

Method1：(no success)

1. set source.list,read readme( from https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/xenial-pgdg/9.4/)
2. download deb package
3. copy them to the target computer
4. dpkg -i *.deb

Method2:(success)

https://techedemic.com/2014/10/01/offline-package-installs-using-dpkg-and-apt-get-ubuntudebianetc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 came with postgresql 9.5, IIRC. So you will need to download the right debian packages (for example from [the postgresql APT package repository](https://apt.postgresql.org)), and transfer them to the target computer), and install them manually (dpkg -i all-dot-deb-files).

But i'd install some newer version of postgres. 9.4 will be end-of-life in one year.